# i m trying to find output (dry run) of the following python list comprehension on pen and paper

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
board=[[3*j+ i+1 for i in range(3)]for j in range(3)]
print(board)
```

**Q.1- What will be equivalent for loop for the same output**
**Q.2- what is the role of 3*j in board[]**
**output is : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]**

Comment: And what is the question? [ask]

Comment: what are you trying to do ? please edit the question and elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the output produced by your list comprehension is not what you show, but actually:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If you did not want to use a list comprehension, perhaps for clarity, then doing the same thing with `for` loops could look something like this:

```
board = []
for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        row.append(j + 1 + i * 3)
    board.append(row)
```

Comment: yes,  you are right, i have edited the question and i was trying to solve it on pane and paper,